# Selion Dependency in the test project

Tags: selenium, paypal

Added selion dependency in maven project. My test cases are not executed .Its ignored with the error ,ClassNotFoundException com.paypal.selion.logger.SeLionLogger".

I have only import the dependency.Never used the API of SeLion.

Test Project with Selenium and TestNG.

I have  tried adding selionFiles in Project folder
Override logging to false.
Nothing works

Comment: How did you add dependency? Maven, Gradle, IDE specific? And which version of SeLion? The ```SeLionLogger``` class is part of ```SeLion-Common-1.2.0.jar``` assuming you are using the current stable version. Is this part of your classpath?

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>com.paypal.selion</groupId>
      <artifactId>SeLion</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>     Which includes Selion Common also